# Convert given timestamp to influxdb timestamp

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, influxdb, node-red

My Incoming Date is in format : `15.08.2017 23:03:23.120000`

Here I am using Node-Red Platform to convert `msg.payload.time` in Influx timestamp but I am getting this Error:

`"Error:` Expected numeric value for, timestamp, but got '15.08.2017 23:03:23.120000'!`"`.

Please let me know the script for given timestamp to influxdb timestamp.

Comment: You put `COIL_ID` in both `fields` and `tags`, is this on purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[InfluxDB expects unix timestamps](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/write_protocols/line_protocol_tutorial/#timestamp) and `msg.payload.time` might be a string, hence you are getting the error.

In order to generate a timeStamp from a date, you can use the `Date` functionality of JS.
It works in the following way:

> `new Date('<your-date-string>').valueOf()`

Here the `date-string` is expected in 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ssZ' format.

In your case, since the `msg.payload.time` is available in `dd.mm.yy hh:mm:ssZ` format, you will need to perform some additional operations.

You can update your code as below:

```
const incomingDate = msg.payload.time;

// extract the date dd.mm.yyyy from the incoming Date String
const splittedDate = incomingDate.split(' ');

// Convert the date from dd.mm.yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd format
let date = splittedDate[0].split('.').reverse().join('-');

// Store time value in a separate variable for later use.
const time = splittedDate[1];

// merge date and time to form yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ssZ format
const datetime = `${date} ${time}`

// assign the timestamp value to fields.time
fields.time =  new Date(datetime).valueOf();
```

Here is a working example

```js
const incomingDate = '15.08.2017 23:03:23.120000';
const splittedDate = incomingDate.split(' ');
let date = splittedDate[0].split('.').reverse().join('-');
const time = splittedDate[1];
const datetime = `${date} ${time}`
console.log(datetime);
console.log(new Date(datetime).valueOf())
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer